# switching between activities and remove previous (only one) intend history stack

Tags: android

I am writing an app which has navigation like that:

start app -> A(home page) -> B -> C -> D

(both of activity B, C, D has the same navigation drawer and it can let users switching pages between B, C, D.)

However, there is a problem when I press back in activity B, C, D.

---

there is an example:

[image]

if I press back in B, then back to home.

if I press back in C, then back to B.

if I press back in D, then back to C.

but this is not what I want.

---

I want to make the flow like below(no matter users is browsing B / C / D, when they press back, then back to home)

i.e.

A(home page) -> B -> (press back) -> A

A(home page) -> B -> C -> (press back) -> A

A(home page) -> B -> C -> D -> (press back) -> A

A(home page) -> B -> C -> D -> B -> D -> (press back) -> A

A(home page) -> B -> C -> B -> D -> (press back) -> A

In other words, I want to make B, C, D be the same level in the navigation hierarchy.

---

Here is my codes of switching activities between B, C, D.

Both of B, C, D have this piece of codes.

The codes bellow is in Activity B:

```
private void switchActivity(){
    NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();

            if(menuItem.getTitle().toString().equals("B")) {
                intent = getIntent();
                finish();
            }
            if(menuItem.getTitle().toString().equals("C")) {
                intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), CActivity.class);
            }
            if(menuItem.getTitle().toString().equals("D")) {
                intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), DActivity.class);
            }

            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this may this help

```
private void switchActivity(){
    NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            if(menuItem.getTitle().toString().equals("B")) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),BActivity.class));
                finish();}

           if(menuItem.getTitle().toString().equals("C")) {
               startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CActivity.class));
               finish();}

          if(menuItem.getTitle().toString().equals("D")) {
               startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DActivity.class));
               finish();}
            return true;
         }
     });
  }

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AActivity.class))   
    finish();
}
```

Comment: It is what I want, but I have to clear the previous flags when I go back to home page by the onBackPressed() method.
So I added this:
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
and it perfectly works as my expected.
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Quick and fast solution would be to use `noHistory=true` on your B,C,D activities in your manifest.xml. With that they all will go back to Activity A `onBackPress()`.

See the docs https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist

Comment: I have tried this.
but it will case another problem which is:
there are ListView in B, C, D. When users click the list item and press back, then it will back to home instead of backing to the ListView page (B, C, D).
sorry for didn't explain clearly in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Override the below method in each of your activities

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```